# Remove all spaces and punctuation (anything not a letter) from a string?

Tags: java, string

In Java, how can I take a string as a parameter, and then remove all punctuation and spaces and then convert the rest of the letters to uppercase?

Example 1:

Input: `How's your day going?`

Output: `HOWSYOURDAYGOING`

Example 2:

Input: `What's your name again?`

Output: `WHATSYOURNAMEAGAIN`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/using-string-replace-in-java and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase() just a start..

Comment: sounds like a combination of Regex and .toUpper() to me.

Comment: this sounds like a job for regular expressions

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick

```
String mystr= "How's your day going?";
mystr = mystr.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "").toUpperCase();
System.out.println(mystr);
```

Output:

```
HOWSYOURDAYGOING
```

The regex `[^A-Za-z]+` means one or more characters that do not match anything in the range `A-Za-z`, and we replace them with the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

```
String yourString = "How's your day going";
yourString=yourString.replaceAll("\\s+",""); //remove white space
yourString=yourString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", ""); //removes all punctuation
yourString=yourString.toUpperCase(); //convert to Upper case
```

Comment: You can still kill off your 2nd line and have your regex handle all characters not in `a-z` and `A-Z`

Comment: Why people keep posting solutions which doesn't contemplate other languages like asian languages?

Answer (score 1):

I did it with

```
inputText = inputText.replaceAll("\\s|[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");


inputText.toUpper();  //and later uppercase the complete string
```

Though @italhourne 's answer is correct but you can just reduce it in single step by just removing the spaces as well as keeping all the characters from a-zA-Z and 0-9, in a single statement by adding "or".
Just a help for those who need it!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String repl1(String n){
    n = n.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\s","");
    return n;
}
```

Comment: sorry for that, now it prints 'heyhemanth' , I removed \s from the expression so that it will not print white spaces

Comment: Taking note of your last line, I've changed the code a bit

Answer (score -2):

Well, I did it the long way, take a look if you want. I used the ACII code values (this is my main method, transform it to a function on your own).

```
String str="How's your day going?";
    char c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        c=str.charAt(i);
        if(c<65||(c>90&&c<97)||(c>122)){
            str=str.replace(str.substring(i,i+1) , "");
        }
    }
    str=str.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(str);
```