# Two string is anagrams ignoring white spaces, capital letters or punctuations

Tags: java

I understand how to check 2 Strings for anagrams. Before that how would I clean up the input strings from white spaces, capital letters and punctuations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946042/remove-all-spaces-and-punctuation-anything-not-a-letter-from-a-string

Comment: Instead of removing spaces, capital letters or punctuation, put a condition in the checkAnagram code for these characters and skip those. This way one iteration can be saved(:P). Can you post your Anagram code, so that we can have a look at that and suggest changes?

Comment: @KrishnaKumar SO isn't the appropriate site for code reviews; the [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is.

Comment: I am not asking for code review, to suggest an answer I am just giving one suggestion, we can point out easily the change based on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`s = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]", "").toLowerCase();`