# How to delete a specific character from a string?

Tags: java, string, csv, jsoup

I'm reading some integer values from a webpage using Java through Jsoup library. In the website integer represented as `xxx,xxx`. I need this set of data to be written in a .csv file so later it can be accessed through Excel for further work.

How to remove this comma in the middle so it doesn't affect the .csv file?

Comment: thisIsTheString.replace(",","");... maybe show some effort from your side

Comment: I was completely out of mind with that.... I thought I should go the index of that comma and manually delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string.replace(",", " "); should do it

Answer (score 1):

```
   if you want to remove any charactor from a string you can use it.

   String name="sri,sha,ila,m";

   name = name.replace(",","");

   Output : srishailam
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be a string when you get it so could use firstInstanceOf to find and then remove it

Answer (score 0):

I believe that string.replace(",", "") will solve your problem.
This question will help [String not replacing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/using-string-replace-in-java).