# How to replace a word with specific word

Tags: java, string

I have a String:

```
String s="<p>Dear <span>{customerName}, your {accountName} is actived </span></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><span>Congrats!.....</span></p>";
```

So I want to take CustomerName and accountName words and replace with customers details. Can anyone please tell me how can I replace. Here customerName and accountName are dynamically changing ..because those are columns in database sometimes different columns. So i want to find the words within the { and } and need to replace with column data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/using-string-replace-in-java

Comment: did you explore `String` api? Didn't you notice `replace()` method?

Comment: sorry here customerName and accountName are dynamically changing ..because those are columns in database sometimes different columns.

Comment: You really should have done more research before asking this. String has an obvious method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
s = s.replace("{customerName}", realCustomerName);
s = s.replace("{accountName}", realAccountNAme);
```

With String's replace function, the first argument is the string you want to replace, and the second argument is the string you want to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s=s.replace('{customerName}',CustomerName ).replace('{accountName}',accountName);
```

where `CustomerName` and `accountName` will be the strings holding your customers details

Comment: Also really hard to read. I would suggest putting code like this on multiple lines.

Comment: actually i need to replace details while sending mail to the customers. Those are not fixed those are database columns and it may be changed dynamically.that is mail template need to send

Comment: So every time you get the values dynamically change and the value of the string with this code

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to replace the words, you could do the following:

```
String s="<p>Dear <span>{customerName}, your {accountName} is actived </span></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><span>Congrats!.....</span></p>";
s.replace( "{customerName}", customer.getName() );
s.replace( "{accountName}", account.getName() );
```

Or, if you are building the string yourself and you can modify it, it might be better to do the following:

```
String s="<p>Dear <span>%1$s, your %1$s is actived </span></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><span>Congrats!.....</span></p>";
// You may also just create a new String object...
s = String.format( s, customer.getName(), account.getName() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer to replace the words using regular expressions. Here words b/w ~ need to replace and these words are not fixed and dynamically will be added to string from UI text Area.

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegularEx {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\~.*?\\~");
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(
            "~ABCD~~BBCc~All the best ~ABCD~~BBCc~~in~~Raja~ Such kind of people ~in~~Raja~~ABCD~~BBCc~~in~~Raja~rajasekhar~ABCD~~BBCc~~in~~Raja~ Bayanapalli ~Chinthalacheruvu~");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    // using Matcher find(), group(), start() and end() methods
    String s1 =new String("~ABCD~~BBCc~All the best ~ABCD~~BBCc~~in~~Raja~ Such kind of people ~in~~Raja~~ABCD~~BBCc~~in~~Raja~rajasekhar~ABCD~~BBCc~~in~~Raja~ Bayanapalli ~Chinthalacheruvu~");
    int i = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String grp = matcher.group();
        int si = matcher.start();
        int ei = matcher.end();
        System.out.println("Found the text \"" + grp

        + "\" starting at " + si + " index and ending at index " + ei);
        s1=s1.replaceAll(grp, "Raja");
        //System.out.println("FinalString" + s1);
    }
    System.out.println("------------------------------------\nFinalString" + s1);

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
 s = s.replace("{customerName}", "John Doe");
 s = s.replace("{accountName}", "jdoe");
```