# Replacing String started with some characters android

Tags: android, string, replace

I want to ask question.

I have a dynamic ocr result like "Prosdfad" or "Pro324sd". And so I want to replace the string to be "Protein". I searched on this site but I haven't found it.
Is there any turorial?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/using-string-replace-in-java

Comment: Please be more specific what you want to replace. Only sdfad or something else.

Comment: so i want to replace "Prosdfad" to "Protein".. all words which contains "Pro" in the beginning will be replaced to protein :)

Comment: woooow... thank you so muuch @KEYSER and all guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
if(str.startsWith("Pro")) {
    str = "Protein";
}
```

Where `str` is your String object.

However, note that it's case-sensitive, so this won't match e.g. `"prosdfad"`. And you might want to consider doing a startsWith check further ahead instead of reassigning the String, if the part to be replaced contains some useful information.

[Here's](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) the String documentation. It has lots of useful methods such as `startsWith`, `toLowerCase`, `matches`, to name a few.