# Java check and parse out string containing character sequence

Tags: java

I need to dynamically check for presence of char sequence "(Self)" in a string and parse it out.

So if my string say myString is

> "ABCDEF (Self)"

it should return myString as

> "ABCDEF"

What is the best way of doing it? Can it be done in a single step?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 returns the string

Comment: Regular Expressions are what you require check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `replace` function as follows:

```
myString = myString.replace(" (Self)","");
```

Here, read more about [things to note with String.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/using-string-replace-in-java) or the [function definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) itself. Note that it is overloaded with a [`char` variant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), so you can do two kinds of things with a similar function call.

Comment: Thx...so it would not show any error even if (Self) is not there in the string ?

Comment: @testndtv It will return the original String if (Self) is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `replaceAll` method from the `String` class as follows:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("(Self)"), ""));
```

Comment: @Hamad I'm confused, i just provided an answer. It's a different answer than the accepted one, but it's not wrong so far... `"ABCDEF (Self)".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("(Self)"), ""));` returns `ABCDEF `... Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry! it was my mistake, i tried to select low quality answer but in haste the other one was selected

Comment: as a sorry i am up voting ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
      String test="ABCDEF (Self)";
      test=test.replaceAll("\\(Self\\)", "");
      System.out.println(test.trim());
```

**Output :**

```
ABCDEF
```

The dig is to use `Regular Expressions` for more on it visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) link.

And the code won't have a problem if there is no `Self` in string.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the String class' public methods.

```
String modifyString(String str) {
    if(str.contains("(Self)")) {
        str = str.replace("(Self)", "");
        str = str.trim();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question, I understand that from source string `ABCDEF (Self)` also the space between `F` and `(` should be removed.
I would recommend to use regEx if you are comfortable with it, else:

```
 String OrigString = "ABCDEF (Self)";
 String newString= OrigString.replaceAll("\\(Self\\)", "").trim();
 System.out.println("New String : --" +newString+"--");
```

The Regular Expression for your case would be:

```
\s*\(Self\)\s*
```

Tested Java Code using regular expression would be:

```
  String newRegExpString = OrigString.replaceAll("\\s*\\(Self\\)\\s*", "");
  System.out.println("New String : -" +newRegExpString+"--");
```

**Output:**

```
New String : --ABCDEF--
New String : -ABCDEF--
```