# What happens with replace method of a String?

Tags: java, string, immutability

We know that the String object is immutable. But replace method is actually changing its state.

So what is happening in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734732/792238

Comment: `But replace method is actually changing its state` Why do you think that's true?

Answer (score 2):

That replace method returns a new string after replacing, not the original one.

Look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28char%2Cchar%29) and see the last line, you'll see that.

```
return new String(0, len, buf);
```

Not only replace almost all the methods, returns new string, not the original.