# Replace C colon drive to c dollar

Tags: java

I tried to replace C:\ to C$ but it is not replace when I used replace method in Java. Is replace method does not accept C:

My string shows C:\Rad\2122\Radn and how to replace C: to C$\Rad\2122\Radn in java.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Show us your code. I suspect that this you may be facing this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/string-replace-not-replacing-characters but I don't want to blindly close your question as duplicate.

Comment: It works fine: http://ideone.com/Ijzn3D

Answer (score 4):

I would use replaceFirst, though replace should also work.

```
path = path.replaceFirst("C:\\\\", "C\\$");
```

The \ needs to escaped twice, once in the regex and also in the String.

```
String path = "C:\\path";
path = path.replaceFirst("C:\\\\", "C\\$");
System.out.println(path);
```

prints

```
C$path
```

Comment: @Pshemo I missed the wanted to replace the \

Comment: This will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference: group index is missing` because `$x` in replacement represents match from group `x`. For instance `replaceFirst("(.)a","$1$1")` will double character before `a` since `$1` is reference to match from group `1`. If we want to create `$` literal we need to escape it with `"\\$"`.

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the `\` character

```
str = str.replace("C:\\", "C$");
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best approach.  Regular expressions just add needless complexity to something that can be kept simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
path = "c$" + path.s.substring(2);
```