# replace method in String class giving different output

Tags: java

In core java API I studied the method `replace(char oldChar,char newChar)` in String class and it says that it will replace the `oldChar` with `newChar` in the string in each occurrence, buy this explanation output of this program given below should be

> A B D C

But the real output is

> A B C C

Can anyone explain me why this is happening so.

```
class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String ta = "A ";
        ta = ta.concat("B ");
        String tb = "C ";
        ta = ta.concat(tb);
        ta.replace('C','D');
        ta = ta.concat(tb);
        System.out.println(ta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely there are about a billion duplicates of this question? Why two answers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12734721/1927206 for instance

Comment: @BillWoodger You can't 'earn' reputation, when you close questions as a duplicate instead of answering. And yes, it is sad that such trusted users do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ta.replace('C','D');
```

This line doesn't change `ta`.  It returns a *new string* with that change made.  You want

```
ta = ta.replace('C','D');
```