# Remove a blank line

Tags: java, regex

I have a file which I convert it into `List<List<String>>`

After doing this, I do some processing and then I need the file (which is now a `List` of `List`) to be converted into a string.

```
private static String convertListOfListToString(List<List<String>> listOfIncomingMsgListsTemp){
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(List<String> listOfString : listOfIncomingMsgListsTemp){
        tempList.add(convertListToString(listOfString));
    }
    String modifiedString = convertListToString(tempList);
    modifiedString.replace("\n\n", "\n");
    System.out.println("modifiedString :\n" + modifiedString);
    return modifiedString;
}

private static String convertListToString(List<String> list){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : list)
    {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return(sb.toString());
}
```

Output : 
When I append List , 2 \n\n are appended. I need to remove those and have only 1 \n.
how can I do that?

Comment: `modifiedString.replace("\n\n", "\n");` should be `modifiedString=modifiedString.replace("\n\n", "\n");`. Possible duplicate (although I didn't test if that is main, or only problem so I will not vote) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/string-not-replacing-characters

Comment: Could replace: `tempList.add(convertListToString(listOfString));` with: `tempList.addAll(listOfString);`.  ie: flatten the list then convert to string in one step.  This would avoid the double `\n` unless you have empty strings.

Comment: Thank You all. I am on Java 6 because my project asks me to. I tried tempList.addAll(listOfString); as suggested by ebyrob and it worked.

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Can you narrow it down to a small handful of lines?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 gives you a pretty elegant way of doing this with streams.

```
String[] text1 = { "hello", "java", "this", "is", "cool" };
String[] text2 = { "hello", "Mundo", "this", "is", "sparta" };
List<String> line = new ArrayList<>();
line.addAll(Arrays.asList(text1));
line.addAll(Arrays.asList(text2));

List<List<String>> doc = new ArrayList<>();
doc.add(line);
doc.add(line);
doc.add(line);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
doc.stream().forEach(a -> a.stream().forEach(x -> sb.append(x)));

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Or `doc.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(sb::append);`. Or `System.out.println(doc.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(joining("\n")));`.