# C# List implementation... in Java

Tags: java, c#, list, intellij-idea, implements

I'm learning Java and I'm trying to do something I've always done in C#... in Java.

The goal is to wrap the class "MyItem" into a List of "MyItems". This makes it easier to reason about (`MyItems` is much easier to read/understand than `List<MyItem>`... or, say, I need to make it something more complicated like `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,List<Dictionary<int,bool>>>>`... then ask for a `MyKVPDictionaries` instead of `List<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<...>>>>>`).

Just looking around... It seems like C# allows you to keep the default implementations of stuff (Look below, .Add just works).

Looking at Java... is there a way to implement a list as done in c#? Or do I have to manually implement the individual parts of the List manually? (.add, .list, .contains, etc).

Below I have a "basic" implementation of a `Class`... and a `List<Class>` in C#.

Is it really that much more work to implement `class MyItems implements List<MyItem>` in Java or am I missing something to simplify the process?

(The Java code is only the `MyItems.java` class file with Resharper "Auto Implement missing members" stubs via IntelliJ).

C# version [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qgEKes):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var myItems = new MyItems();
        myItems.Add(new MyItem("Hello"));
        myItems.Add(new MyItem(" "));
        myItems.Add(new MyItem("World"));
        myItems.Add(new MyItem("!"));
                    
        foreach(var item in myItems)
            Console.Write(item.Name);
    }
}

public class MyItems : List<MyItem>
{
    
}

public class MyItem
{
    public MyItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Java Version start/stub:

```
package items;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyItems implements List<MyItem> {
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<MyItem> iterator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(MyItem generatePreSignedUrl) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends MyItem> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends MyItem> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {

    }

    @Override
    public MyItem get(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public MyItem set(int index, MyItem element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, MyItem element) {

    }

    @Override
    public MyItem remove(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<MyItem> listIterator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<MyItem> listIterator(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyItem> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generic `List` in java is not a class its an interface. That's why you need to implement all of its members . You can inherit `ArrayList` which implements `List`.  `public class MyItems extends ArrayList<MyItem>`

Comment: "I" ditched you.

Answer (score 7):

Java's `List` type is an interface, the counterpart of C#'s `IList`. You'll have to write most of the methods from scratch if you want to implement it. The counterpart of C#'s concrete `List` class would be Java's `ArrayList`:

```
public class MyItems extends ArrayList<MyItem> {
```

Comment: Ahh... I knew I was missing something basic. I think that'll get me in the right direction.

Comment: @WernerCD I suggest you familiarize yourself with [the Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) (This link is for Java 7. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to find the docs for Java 8 if needed.) These docs tell you what names are classes and which are interfaces. Unlike C#, Java programmers typically do not start interface names with `I`.

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my next question... C# and Java are very similar... but very different. I have a good basics book but was trying to do something beyond where I'm at in Java. I'll admit, I wouldn't have considered IList/List vs List/ArrayList. It doesn't help that the terminology is different and ArrayList is an older version of a List in C# (List is generic and ArrayList is objects).

Comment: @WernerCD `ArrayList` is generic since Java 5.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Oohhhhh.... Difficult exercise: Replace `7` with `8` in the URL... Tough assignment you gave there. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas Don't laugh, [replacing is tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12734721/1553851).

Comment: @WernerCD All of the Java Collections API is generic since Java 5. Even the antiquated `Vector` which no one should use any more.