# some issue in converting lowercase letter and replace function

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class StringTest{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s1 = "A", s2="a", s3="b";
    s1.toLowerCase();
    s3.replace('b','a');
    System.out.println((s1.equals(s2))+","+(s2.equals(s3)));
    System.out.println(s1+" "+s2+" "+s3);
}
}
```

Expected output:

```
true, true
a a a
```

but toLowerCase() and replace() fuction is not working and i am getting the output as:

```
false,false
A a b
```

i am new to java programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String replace method is not replacing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/string-replace-method-is-not-replacing-characters)

Comment: Strings are immutable. Meaning the vslue can't be modified which us why toLowerCase returns a new string rather than modify the input. Same goes for replace method.

Comment: Strings are immutable objects created on heap, and if you are using replace function please assign it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not assign value to the variable after conversion. Please replace those 2 functions with

```
s1=s1.toLowerCase();
s3=s3.replace('b','a');
```

Answer (score 2):

The Answers above are Right.

But as a beginner, what I want to you you understand is that Strings and Primitives in Java are immutable *meaning the Values they are assigned to can't change*

In your situation above you could do

```
String s1 = "A", s2="a", s3="b";
 
System.out.println( s1.toLowerCase());
```

To verify that the toLowerCase() methods works or you reassign the variable

```
s1 = s1.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1.toLowerCase();
```

this works exactly as you would expect, but it doesn't change the assigned version.

You want:

```
s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
```

For the replace method, its the same issue: the correct value is returned, but you don't assign it to your variable.